# Saving state of spinners between activites

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to android but having trouble saving my activity state, specifically my spinners so they retain their value.

I've tried both savedinstancestate and preferences and I can still get neither to work, just wondering if someone could take a look at my code and see where I've gone wrong.

```
public class YearOneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button ButtonSubmit;
Spinner SpinnerGradesUnitOne, SpinnerGradesUnitTwo, SpinnerGradesUnitThree, SpinnerGradesUnitSix, SpinnerGradesUnitNine, SpinnerGradesUnitTwentySix, SpinnerGradesUnitEighteen, SpinnerGradesUnitTwentyEight, SpinnerGradesUnitFortyThree;
int spinnerUnit1;

public void SubmitMainActivity(){
    ButtonSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
    ButtonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent SubmitMainActivity = new Intent(YearOneActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(SubmitMainActivity);
        }
    });
}

public void SpinnerGrades(){
    SpinnerGradesUnitOne = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_one);
    SpinnerGradesUnitTwo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_two);
    SpinnerGradesUnitThree = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_three);
    SpinnerGradesUnitSix = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_six);
    SpinnerGradesUnitNine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_nine);
    SpinnerGradesUnitTwentySix = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_twentysix);
    SpinnerGradesUnitEighteen = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_eighteen);
    SpinnerGradesUnitTwentyEight = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_twentyeight);
    SpinnerGradesUnitFortyThree = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_grades_unit_fortythree);

    String[] spinnerArrayGrades = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_grades);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterGrades = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArrayGrades);

    SpinnerGradesUnitOne.setAdapter(adapterGrades);

    SpinnerGradesUnitTwo.setAdapter(adapterGrades);
    SpinnerGradesUnitThree.setAdapter(adapterGrades);
    SpinnerGradesUnitSix.setAdapter(adapterGrades);
    SpinnerGradesUnitNine.setAdapter(adapterGrades);
    SpinnerGradesUnitTwentySix.setAdapter(adapterGrades);
    SpinnerGradesUnitEighteen.setAdapter(adapterGrades);
    SpinnerGradesUnitTwentyEight.setAdapter(adapterGrades);
    SpinnerGradesUnitFortyThree.setAdapter(adapterGrades);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_year_one);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){

        SpinnerGradesUnitOne.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit1", 0));
        SpinnerGradesUnitTwo.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit2", 0));
        SpinnerGradesUnitThree.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit3", 0));
        SpinnerGradesUnitSix.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit6", 0));
        SpinnerGradesUnitNine.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit9", 0));
        SpinnerGradesUnitTwentySix.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit26", 0));
        SpinnerGradesUnitEighteen.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit18", 0));
        SpinnerGradesUnitTwentyEight.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit28", 0));
        SpinnerGradesUnitFortyThree.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("spinnerUnit43", 0));

    }

    SubmitMainActivity();
    SpinnerGrades();

}

@Override
public  void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit1", SpinnerGradesUnitOne.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit2", SpinnerGradesUnitTwo.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit3", SpinnerGradesUnitThree.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit6", SpinnerGradesUnitSix.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit9", SpinnerGradesUnitNine.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit26", SpinnerGradesUnitTwentySix.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit18", SpinnerGradesUnitEighteen.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit28", SpinnerGradesUnitTwentyEight.getSelectedItemPosition());
    outState.putInt("spinnerUnit43", SpinnerGradesUnitFortyThree.getSelectedItemPosition());

}
```

Comment: You may want to explain what the problem is that you're having.

Comment: I'm trying to make the spinners maintain their selection when the user navigates between activities, currently they get wiped each time.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Spinners maintain their state automatically, when you provide an unique I'd to them in the layout xml. If that's not the case you should use onSaveInstanceState like you did.
If your code is as is showed above I'm absolutely wondering why you don't receive an NullpointerException. At the moment your setting the old Spinner' states BEFORE even you have initialized them in your new activity. Thus try to move the last method calls before your if-block. Then it should work:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_year_one);

    SubmitMainActivity();
    SpinnerGrades();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried doing as you've said but it has not worked, is there any other way of saving the spinners inputs?